# SPARQL query to return date from a turtle file

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, turtle-rdf

What would be the syntax for the SPARQL query to return all journals between 2001-2017 from the following Turtle file?

```
@prefix c:<http://www.example.com/journal#> .


c:article1 c:title "Benifits of Computer" .
c:article1 c:author "Jhon Maur" .
c:article1 c:topic "Computers" .
c:article1 c:date "12/02/1978" .

c:article2 c:title "Eating Healthier" .
c:article2 c:author "Dr. Joe Green" .
c:article2 c:topic "Health" .
c:article2 c:date "10/13/1999" .

c:article3 c:title "Sports in America" .
c:article3 c:author "Tom Golds" .
c:article3 c:topic "Sports" .
c:article3 c:date "02/09/2004" .

c:article4 c:title "Students Jobs" .
c:article4 c:author "Harry Parsons" .
c:article4 c:topic "Commentary" .
c:article4 c:date "09/19/2012" .

c:article5 c:title "The Golden Age of IT" .
c:article5 c:author "Jhon Maur" .
c:article5 c:topic "Computers" .
c:article5 c:date "12/02/1990" .

c:article6 c:title "Health Foods to Avoid" .
c:article6 c:author "Dr. Joe Green" .
c:article6 c:topic "Heallth" .
c:article6 c:date "10/13/2007" .

c:article7 c:title "Boutique Languages" .
c:article7 c:author "Allister Rhodes" .
c:article7 c:topic "Computers" .
c:article7 c:date "02/09/2004" .

c:article8 c:title "Big Brother or Government" .
c:article8 c:author "Tomas Weiss" .
c:article8 c:topic "Commentary" .
c:article8 c:date "03/09/2016" .

c:article9 c:title "Getting a Good Job" .
c:article9 c:author "Joan Wiley" .
c:article9 c:topic "Commentary" .
c:article9 c:date "07/11/2014" .

c:article10 c:title "Scheduling Jobs in Python" .
c:article10 c:author "Tony Issacs" .
c:article10 c:topic "Computers" .
c:article10 c:date "01/09/2017" .
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're only using strings to represent dates, then you'd have to essentially do some string parsing to get the years out.  Instead, you should use actual datatyped literals (probably **xsd:dateTime**) to represent time, so that you can use the [year](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-year) function, and then just do something like this:

```sql
select ?article { 
  ?article c:date ?date 
  filter (2001 <= year(?date) && year(?date) <= 2017)
}
```

If you're really committed to using strings of the form "mm/dd/yyyy" for dates, then you can extract the values like this:

```sql
select ?article { 
  ?article c:date ?date 
  bind(?year as xsd:int(substr(?date, 7)))
  filter (2001 <= ?year && ?year <= 2017)
}
```